# How to fix "Laravel Middleware clearing requests headers"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

i want to pass request headers to Controller after middleware has validated access but i get clear request object

**api.php**

```php
Route::put('panels/edit/{id}', 'PanelsController@edit')
    ->middleware('ApiAuthenticate');
```

**apiAuthenicated Middleware**

```php
class ApiAuthenticated {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) 
    {   
        // return response($request->headers); is working and i can get headers

        // i have tries also to do this
        // return $next($request)->header('header_key','header_value');

        // but i still get cleared headers in controller

        return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function edit($panel_id)
{
    return request()->headers  // ... it gives me []   
}
```

Comment: There must be some other middleware wiping the headers?